# How do I iterate and Input value multiple List<WebElement> in selenium /Java

Tags: selenium

I have the following WebElement List in a page

```
@FindBy(xpath="a")
private List<WebElement> generalList ;
@FindBy(xpath="b")
private List<WebElement> eventList ;
@FindBy(xpath="c")
private List<WebElement> additionalList ;
```

I want to iterate each of the above list items and input values through a loop

Example

**Generalist**

**Last Name:** last name (input field)

**First Name:** First Name (input field)

**AdditionalList**

**Address :** Adress (input field)

**Zip** :11423 (input field)

I have tried the following

```
generalList.stream().forEach(elem -> elem.sendkeys("last name"," First Name"));
```

Its entering lastnameFirstname in each input field.

Last Name: lastnameFirstname

First Name: lastnameFirstname

Answer (score 1):

Your code already iterates the list and enters data in each element.

Honestly, this is not a good way to do this. I'm guessing you might think this is more efficient or whatever but it just makes it more confusing. Just `.sendKeys()` to Last Name, then First Name, and so on. Doing it this way makes it more clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looping through WebElement and provide same value during `sendKeys()` that's why you are getting same output which is absolutely correct. You need to loop through value which you want to set on input field instead as below :-

```
String[] names = {"Last Name", "First Name"};
IntStream.range(0, names.length).forEach(idx -> generalList.get(idx).sendKeys(names[idx]));
```